Problema de 401
Hola buenas estoy terminando un proyecto de microservicios, estaba aplicando la seguridad en mi gateway no puedo hacer una orden porque me tira el status 401, En mis demas componentes como productos, clientes las peticiones andan bien pero cuando creo el order no, capaz porque en order la pide al componente Customer le pide el servicio de buscar cliente
Clase Config Segurity
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity serverHttpSecurity){
        serverHttpSecurity
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
                        .pathMatchers("(/eureka/**)")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyExchange()
                        .authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        return serverHttpSecurity.build();
    }


}

Peticion en Postman

Esos son los datos que me prove keycloak admin
Aclaracion :
los clientes Feign no tienen acceso de autenticación a otros servicios. Esto se debe a que los tokens de autenticación solo están disponibles para el servicio al que se les pasa el token junto con la solicitud API. Este problema está causando que el order-service deje de funcionar, y sugiere que la integración con Keycloak debe implementarse manualmente en el order-service para resolver el problema.
Le pregunte a GPT me dio esto que ocupan :
Configurar el interceptor OAuth2 para Feign
@Component
public class FeignOAuth2Interceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager;

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = authorizedClientManager.authorize(
                OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("customer")
                        .principal("micro-services-api")
                        .build());

        if (client != null) {
            template.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
        }
    }
}

Registrar el interceptor en la configuración de Feign
@Configuration
public class FeignConfig {

    @Bean
    public FeignOAuth2Interceptor feignOAuth2Interceptor() {
        return new FeignOAuth2Interceptor();
    }
}

Configurar OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

        return new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
    }
}

Asegurarse de que el cliente Feign esté configurado para usar el interceptor
Lo que me muestra :
@FeignClient(name = "customer-service", configuration = FeignConfig.class)
public interface CustomerServiceClient {
    // Métodos de interfaz para acceder a customer-service
}

Lo que tengo yo:
@FeignClient(
        name = "customer-service",
        url = "${application.config.customer-url}"
)
public interface CustomerClient {

    @GetMapping("/{customer-id}")
    Optional<CustomerResponse> findCustomerById(@PathVariable("customer-id") String customerId);
}

Pasar el token entre servicios
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2Login()
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt();
    
    return http.build();
}

